# DPI scaling problem with hosted native HWND control inside WPF window

Tags: c#, wpf, scale

I have a high dpi setting on my monitor as the monitor is a fairly small 3840 x 2160 monitor.

This is causing issues with one of the applications I am writing as I am hosting a control in my main application. I developed it based off a nice example in the [WPF-Samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/WPF-Samples/tree/master/Migration%20and%20Interoperability/WPFHostingWin32Control).

On my screen, when the example is run in it's default state, the output looks like

[image]

I was able to account for the list control being the incorrect size by using

```
//MainWindow
PresentationSource source = PresentationSource.FromVisual(this); //Account for any scaling on the screen7
_listControl = new ControlHost(ControlHostElement.ActualWidth, ControlHostElement.ActualHeight, source.CompositionTarget.TransformToDevice.M11, source.CompositionTarget.TransformToDevice.M22);

...

//ControlHost
public ControlHost(double height, double width, double dpXScale, double dpYScale)
{
    _hostHeight = (int) (height * dpXScale);
    _hostWidth = (int) (width * dpYScale);
}
```

[image]

However, even when it is the correct size, the hosted UI is not scaled as the rest of the program is.

How could the program scale the hosted UI based on the DPI of the user's screen?

---

There are three main files that make up the this example.

*ControlHost.cs*

```
// // Copyright (c) Microsoft. All rights reserved.
// // Licensed under the MIT license. See LICENSE file in the project root for full license information.

#region Using directives

using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Interop;

#endregion

namespace WPFHostingWin32Control
{
    public class ControlHost : HwndHost
    {
        internal const int
            WsChild = 0x40000000,
            WsVisible = 0x10000000,
            LbsNotify = 0x00000001,
            HostId = 0x00000002,
            ListboxId = 0x00000001,
            WsVscroll = 0x00200000,
            WsBorder = 0x00800000;

        private readonly int _hostHeight;
        private readonly int _hostWidth;
        private IntPtr _hwndHost;

        public ControlHost(double height, double width, double dpXScale, double dpYScale)
        {
            _hostHeight = (int) (height * dpXScale);
            _hostWidth = (int) (width * dpYScale);
        }

        public IntPtr HwndListBox { get; private set; }

        protected override HandleRef BuildWindowCore(HandleRef hwndParent)
        {
            HwndListBox = IntPtr.Zero;
            _hwndHost = IntPtr.Zero;

            _hwndHost = CreateWindowEx(0, "static", "",
                WsChild | WsVisible,
                0, 0,
                _hostHeight, _hostWidth,
                hwndParent.Handle,
                (IntPtr) HostId,
                IntPtr.Zero,
                0);

            HwndListBox = CreateWindowEx(0, "listbox", "",
                WsChild | WsVisible | LbsNotify
                | WsVscroll | WsBorder,
                0, 0,
                _hostHeight, _hostWidth,
                _hwndHost,
                (IntPtr) ListboxId,
                IntPtr.Zero,
                0);

            return new HandleRef(this, _hwndHost);
        }

        protected override IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
        {
            handled = false;
            return IntPtr.Zero;
        }

        protected override void DestroyWindowCore(HandleRef hwnd)
        {
            DestroyWindow(hwnd.Handle);
        }

        //PInvoke declarations
        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "CreateWindowEx", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        internal static extern IntPtr CreateWindowEx(int dwExStyle,
            string lpszClassName,
            string lpszWindowName,
            int style,
            int x, int y,
            int width, int height,
            IntPtr hwndParent,
            IntPtr hMenu,
            IntPtr hInst,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.AsAny)] object pvParam);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "DestroyWindow", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        internal static extern bool DestroyWindow(IntPtr hwnd);
    }
}
```

*MainWindow.xaml*

```
<Window x:Class="WPFHostingWin32Control.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPFHostingWin32Control"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Loaded="On_UIReady">

  <DockPanel Background="LightGreen">
    <Border Name="ControlHostElement"
    Width="200"
    Height="200"
    HorizontalAlignment="Right"
    VerticalAlignment="Top"
    BorderBrush="LightGray"
    BorderThickness="3"
    DockPanel.Dock="Right"/>
    <StackPanel>
      <Label HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        Margin="0,10,0,0"
        FontSize="14"
        FontWeight="Bold">Control the Control</Label>
      <TextBlock Margin="10,10,10,10" >Selected Text: <TextBlock  Name="selectedText"/></TextBlock>
      <TextBlock Margin="10,10,10,10" >Number of Items: <TextBlock  Name="numItems"/></TextBlock>

      <Line X1="0" X2="200"
        Stroke="LightYellow"
        StrokeThickness="2"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        Margin="0,20,0,0"/>

      <Label HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        Margin="10,10,10,10">Append an Item to the List</Label>
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Label HorizontalAlignment="Left"
          Margin="10,10,10,10">Item Text</Label>
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left"
          Name="txtAppend"
          Width="200"
          Margin="10,10,10,10" />
      </StackPanel>

      <Button HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        Click="AppendText"
        Width="75"
        Margin="10,10,10,10">Append</Button>

      <Line X1="0" X2="200"
        Stroke="LightYellow"
        StrokeThickness="2"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        Margin="0,20,0,0"/>

      <Label HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        Margin="10,10,10,10">Delete the Selected Item</Label>

      <Button Click="DeleteText"
        Width="125"
        Margin="10,10,10,10"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left">Delete</Button>
    </StackPanel>
  </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

*MainWindow.cs*

```
// // Copyright (c) Microsoft. All rights reserved.
// // Licensed under the MIT license. See LICENSE file in the project root for full license information.

using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;

namespace WPFHostingWin32Control
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        internal const int
            LbnSelchange = 0x00000001,
            WmCommand = 0x00000111,
            LbGetcursel = 0x00000188,
            LbGettextlen = 0x0000018A,
            LbAddstring = 0x00000180,
            LbGettext = 0x00000189,
            LbDeletestring = 0x00000182,
            LbGetcount = 0x0000018B;

        private Application _app;
        private IntPtr _hwndListBox;
        private int _itemCount;
        private ControlHost _listControl;
        private Window _myWindow;
        private int _selectedItem;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void On_UIReady(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _app = Application.Current;
            _myWindow = _app.MainWindow;
            _myWindow.SizeToContent = SizeToContent.WidthAndHeight;

            PresentationSource source = PresentationSource.FromVisual(this); //Account for any scaling on the screen7

            _listControl = new ControlHost(ControlHostElement.ActualWidth, ControlHostElement.ActualHeight, source.CompositionTarget.TransformToDevice.M11, source.CompositionTarget.TransformToDevice.M22);
            ControlHostElement.Child = _listControl;
            _listControl.MessageHook += ControlMsgFilter;
            _hwndListBox = _listControl.HwndListBox;
            for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) //populate listbox
            {
                var itemText = "Item" + i;
                SendMessage(_hwndListBox, LbAddstring, IntPtr.Zero, itemText);
            }
            _itemCount = SendMessage(_hwndListBox, LbGetcount, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
            numItems.Text = "" + _itemCount;
        }

        private void AppendText(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            if (txtAppend.Text != string.Empty)
            {
                SendMessage(_hwndListBox, LbAddstring, IntPtr.Zero, txtAppend.Text);
            }
            _itemCount = SendMessage(_hwndListBox, LbGetcount, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
            numItems.Text = "" + _itemCount;
        }

        private void DeleteText(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            _selectedItem = SendMessage(_listControl.HwndListBox, LbGetcursel, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
            if (_selectedItem != -1) //check for selected item
            {
                SendMessage(_hwndListBox, LbDeletestring, (IntPtr) _selectedItem, IntPtr.Zero);
            }
            _itemCount = SendMessage(_hwndListBox, LbGetcount, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
            numItems.Text = "" + _itemCount;
        }

        private IntPtr ControlMsgFilter(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
        {
            int textLength;

            handled = false;
            if (msg == WmCommand)
            {
                switch ((uint) wParam.ToInt32() >> 16 & 0xFFFF) //extract the HIWORD
                {
                    case LbnSelchange: //Get the item text and display it
                        _selectedItem = SendMessage(_listControl.HwndListBox, LbGetcursel, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
                        textLength = SendMessage(_listControl.HwndListBox, LbGettextlen, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
                        var itemText = new StringBuilder();
                        SendMessage(_hwndListBox, LbGettext, _selectedItem, itemText);
                        selectedText.Text = itemText.ToString();
                        handled = true;
                        break;
                }
            }
            return IntPtr.Zero;
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SendMessage", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        internal static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hwnd,
            int msg,
            IntPtr wParam,
            IntPtr lParam);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SendMessage", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        internal static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hwnd,
            int msg,
            int wParam,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] StringBuilder lParam);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SendMessage", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        internal static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hwnd,
            int msg,
            IntPtr wParam,
            string lParam);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why go to all that trouble to host a native HWND listbox that doesn't scale?   Why not use a WPF listbox that does support DPI scaling?

Comment: @MickyD Apologies for not making it clearer. I am not going to all this trouble to host a list box. This was just a nice example I found for a MCVE but it is the same concept. I have a native control that I can't replace with a WPF control. However, the same problem still exists that it is not scaling. The question really is about is there anyway to make a native control DPI aware as it would be if that control were run in a native application as the system (assuming your on Windows 10) makes it scale up

Comment: @MickyD If the answer is simply no or the native control would have to be written to be made scalable before usage in this manner, then that is not a problem

Comment: Generally this sort of thing is controlled by the application manifest or perhaps a simple p-invoke to `SetProcessDpiAwareness(PROCESS_PER_MONITOR_DPI_AWARE)`.  Check out this article for possible tips _[Windows with C++ : Write High-DPI Apps for Windows 8.1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn574798.aspx)_

Comment: The control should have `EnableWindowsFormsHighDpiAutoResizing` set to true. This is straight from the manifest file. Also set the `dpiAware` to true.

Comment: Thank you both for the help

Comment: You are most welcome good sir.

Answer (score 1):

Winforms does not handle high-DPI settings very well by default. As stated in the comments, you can try some of the available manifest settings to get it to resize. If that won't work for your situation then you will need to scale the control yourself. Most Winforms controls have a Scale method you could call when you adjust the height and width:

```
_listControl.Scale(dpXScale, dpYScale);
```

of course, since your actual code uses a custom control your mileage may vary.

Comment: Thanks. That happens to work for some of my components but not all